# Scrypt fails at verifyKdf with just "Error"

Tags: node.js, scrypt

I've setup Scrypt and hashing - the KDF - works fine.

However, whenever I try to `verifyKdf()` I get an error.

> return scryptNative.verifySync(args[0], args[1]);
>                           ^
>
> Error
>
> at Object.verifyKdfSync (/home/arc/Desktop/scrypt-test/node_modules/scrypt/index.js:331:25)

My code to hash it.

```
// a promise chain...

.then(() => scrypt.kdf(newPassword, scryptParameters))
.then(hashedPassword => {

    user.hashedPassword = hashedPassword.toString('base64')

    resolve(store.save(user.id, user))

})
```

then to verify: (here it falls into the `catch()` and `err` simple contains "Error")

```
scrypt.verifyKdf(user.hashdPassword, enteredPassword)
    .then(result => {
            if (result) return resolve(user)
            else return reject('Wrong password')
     })
     .catch(err => {
            console.log('scrypt verify failed: ', err)
            return reject('Internal Error')
     })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is that `.toString('base64')` is used. Although this in itself is not a problem, you have to revert it back to a buffer.

To fix it use `new Buffer( /* Password */ , 'base64')` and would look like this:

```
scrypt.verifyKdf(new Buffer(user.hasdPassword, 'base64'), password)
```

This solution would work as well when instead of `base64` `hex` was used.